# Using locateResource inside Twig Extension

Tags: php, symfony, kernel, twig, twig-extension

I wish to use the following inside of a Twig Extension

```
$kernel = $container->getService('kernel');
$path = $kernel->locateResource('@AdmeDemoBundle/path/to/file/Foo.png');
```

but this involved passing in the Kernel, which is bad. Plus I could not get it to work anyway when trying this method.

How can I access a resources path within a Twig Extension?

The Extension is already a Service. I can use Assetic to give me the URL, but I really want the path.

Comment: can you wrap it into a service  (so you can use it elsewhere also) and use the service in the extension?

Comment: It's in a service already. I'll edit and make that clearer. How do I get what I need into the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar need: i needed to pass to the filter the url of an image to display it in a `for` loop and build a string.

I passed the URL directly to the filter in this way:

```
{%  image '@AppBundle/Resources/public/images/my_asset.png' %}
    {% set resolved_asset_url = asset_url %}
{% endimage %}

{{ my_var|filter_name(resolved_asset_url)|raw(html) }}
```

In this way the Twig template resolve the correct resource's URL, sets it as a variable, and then I pass it to the filter from inside the template itself, without having to deal with `kernel` or something else.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to serve a download, you should create a Route that accomplishes that task.

In this way, you'll call the locator inside the route, and a simple

```
{{ path('route_that_does_the_locator_thing') }}
```

will be fine.

If you need instead to include a file in your template (ex. CSS, JS..), you need to declare your file as an asset, maybe using Assetic.

Comment: Its an image I wish to locate, using Assetic give me the URL, which is not great. I want the path.

Comment: Why do you need the path instead of the URL?

Comment: Because I want to use `file_get_contents` as well as other things. Using the URL is slower.

Comment: And why do you need it? You need to edit the image? BTW, still, if you need all those things, you shouldn't do it in a Twig extension! That's not the proper place

Comment: I wish to get the data-uri of the image

Comment: You shouldn't implement it yourself... Assetic already has a filter to do it, look it up `phpcssembed`

Comment: I still want to do it myself though, as I need to amend the SVGs